# How to implment CSRF Spring Security with Angular for microservices system?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I have angular with spring boot 2.7.3 (so spring security 6 won't work).
In auth server I started with this (this code set the cockiem but if the first
request is post, it won't work):

```
security.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());

@Bean
        public CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            CookieCsrfTokenRepository repository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
            repository.setCookiePath("/");         
            repository.setCookieHttpOnly(false);
            repository.setSecure(false); 
            return repository;
        }
```

In angular I have the following (this allow angular to send the header automatically):

```
 HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
        cookieName: 'name',
        headerName: 'name'
      }),
```

In order to solve the first request, I added request on AppModule to this end point:

```
@GetMapping("/csrf-token")  
    public CsrfToken csrf(CsrfToken csrfToken) {
        return csrfToken;
    }
```

This code generate the token (if not found) but when it send back, I have this token in the
angular service but also in the cockie (doesn't make sense to me).

Now, the question, I can't make all resource microsoervices to send token, so I can't do this I guess there:

```
CookieCsrfTokenRepository repository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
```

I don't like to make api call to the auth server for each request and I don't wish to store
anything in the DB. But, the resource server need to validate the token (not just confirm it exist). I was thinkging about kafka message from the auth, when it generate new token, so that's means I need customization on the genrate code (produce message there)? But, this means map with tokens for each microservice! also, angualr might sent request to the resorce server before the mesasge consumed. am I wrong or missing something?

Comment: The HttpClientXsrfModule reads the cookie that has been set from the server on the previous response... The module reads that cookie and sends it as the header for every request.  cookieName sets the cookie it reads... headerName sets the name of the header it sends.   Since GET requests should not change state, you don't need CSRF tokens for GETs.  No need to check header for token there.  Only when changing state on POST, or other verb would you want that.  Also be aware that if you do not send credentials via cookie (or other automatic method) you won't need CSRF tokens at all.

Comment: you are saying that login/refresh token request doesn't need CSRF  protextion?

Comment: If those are sent in the header, then no.  CSRF happens when a user is tricked into sending a request that also sends credentials.  (usually via cookie)  Sending custom headers cannot be done with a standard POST, and sending via JS call would trigger preflight check.  As long as you are not allowing the attacker's domain to make cross-site requests, you should be fine.  Anti-csrf tokens can still be useful against CRIME/BREACH attacks if each form has a unique anti-csrf token.